# Backslash in query param

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

If I use a query param with backslashes in it, angular will replace them with normal slashes and recognizes them as path seperators on page reload.

I'm using the `routerLink` inside my HTML like this:

```
<li [routerLink]="['Detail', { ID: unit.ID}]" *ngFor="#unit of units">{{unit.name}}</li>
```

Example for unit.ID is `R0010\U001` (after escaping)

Why isn't angular encoding the param? How can I fix this easily?

Comment: Looks similar to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7333. It might need to be consider in https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7312/files like `=` and `/`.

Comment: Oh. Thank you. However I did not find this after googling a while.

Comment: I remembered seeing the recently which makes it easier to find.